# how to get picture inside div?

Tags: css, image, html

I have this div that I have placed with a z-index over another div. I tried putting a picture inside my div, but it doesn't work. How do I place my flower inside the red box? Now it's on another picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now define

`.tm_top` `class` `position:relative;` **because this is** `parent` to `#latestcircle` `id`

and **define** your `id` `#latestcircle` `position: absolute; left:0; top:0;`

**as like this  css**

```
.tm_top{
position:relative;
}
#latestcircle{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: image clip]try this 
CSS

```
#latestcircle img{
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ## latestcircle {
>
> ```
> height: 100px;
> position: absolute;
> width: 100px;
> z-index: 10000000;
> ```
>
> }